# Is it possible to do validation in beforeDestroy of vue.js and prevent unmount of component if validation fails?

Tags: vue.js

I want to run certain validation in beforeDestroy(may be better alternate lifecycle method) of vuejs and prevent unmount of the component if validation fails. I am able to run the validation but I don't know how to prevent unmount/destroy of the component.

```
beforeDestroy(){
  if(validationfails) {
    return;
  }
}
```